# AEM 6.1 Touch UI and cq:actions with 'editannotate' does not work

Tags: javascript, java, aem

I have a problem with adding annotation for components in AEM 6.1. I add in component node `cq:EditConfig` property `cq:Actions` with value `EDITANNOTATE`, but annotations don't work for this component.
When I remove property `cq:Actions` I can annotate, but I want to set custom actions for component.

How I can set Annotate action for component?

[image: This component in CRX reposiory]

[image: Click Annotate button]

[image: Can't annotate my component]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, I've found answer - this is a bug of AEM. I check it on AEM 6.2 SP1 - action `EDITANNOTATION` works.